# How to post a json array to java servlet with jquery

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring

I'm currently developing `spring mvc` application and I need to post `JSON array`.

When I access `request.getParameter("paramValue")` to fetch the param attibute, but it returning a `null` value,

Here is my front-end code:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    async: true,
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:  JSON.stringify({
        "test":"test value"
    })
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (xhr) {
    console.log("request failed");
    console.log(xhr);
});
```

Here is my server-side code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Products", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveProducts(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(req.getContentType());
    System.out.println(req.getContentLength());
    System.out.println(req.getContextPath());
    System.out.println(req.getParameterValues("test"));
    System.out.println(req.getMethod());

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line);
    }
    String data = buffer.toString();

    System.out.println(data);

    System.out.println(req.getParameter("test"));
}
```

The output is:

```
application/json
22

null
POST
{"test" : "Test DAta"}
null
```

I can't figure out whats going on, please help me.

Comment: You send object, not param. Possible duplicate

Comment: no i tried JSON.stringify() also

Answer (score 0):

remove this line in you ajax function

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

and replace this line

```
data:  JSON.stringify({
        "test":"test value"
    })
```

with

```
data: {
   "test":"test value"
}
```

and also you can use

```
req.getParameter("test")
```

instead

```
req.getParameterValues("test")
```

Comment: still it print out a null value

Comment: @SelvaduraiHandeeban I've updated the code please check

Answer (score 0):

You can by using this :

```
var data ={id: 1, name :'test'}


       $.ajax(url, {
        async: true,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        console.log("request failed");
        console.log(xhr);
    });
```

and  in server side 
create a pojo  :

```
public class Product{
  private long id;
  private String name;
 // getters and setters
```

add  library jackson .

add this method in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Products", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RepsoneEntity<? >saveProducts(@requestBody Product pr){
     LOG.debug(pr.toString());
  return new reRepsoneEntity<Product>(pr,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally fixed it several annotation and changing the the return type of server side method,

`@RequestMapping(value = "/Products", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces =             "application/json;charset=UTF-8")`

```
public ResponseEntity<?> saveProducts(@RequestParam(value = "data") String brand) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(brand);
}</code>
```

front end

`$.ajax(url, {
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            data: {"data" : JSON.stringify({"Brand" : "Test Brand"})}`

```
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        console.log("request failed");
        console.log(xhr);
    });
```

and i used org.json to access json objects parsed as text, gson to deal with POJOs

and now it works :)